# changing spaces between rows in Skeleton Framework.

Tags: html, css, frameworks

Right now I have two divs using "one-half columns" class.

As you can see here, the bottom card on the left side is still aligned with the one on the bottom right.  [image]

I want Pinterest kind of style like this, but I do not know how because they are in different rows.[image]

here is my html code.

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
  <div id="cards" class="one-half column" style="margin-top: 25%">
    <img class="card-image" src="img/sample.png">
    <div class="title">
    <h4>Stealth Rats</h4>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus suscipit eu nibh vitae maximus.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
   <div id="cards" class="one-half column" style="margin-top: 25%">
    <img class="card-image" src="img/sample.png">
    <div class="title">
    <h4>Basic Page</h4>
    <p>This index.html page is a placeholder with the CSS, font and favicon. It's just waiting for you to add some content! If you need some help hit up the <a href="http://www.getskeleton.com">Skeleton documentation</a>.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus suscipit eu nibh vitae maximus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc a mollis arcu.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div id="cards" class="one-half column" style="margin-top: 5%">
  <img class="card-image" src="img/sample.png">
    <h4>Basic Page</h4>
    <p>This index.html page is a placeholder with the CSS, font and favicon. It's just waiting for you to add some content! If you need some help hit up the <a href="http://www.getskeleton.com">Skeleton documentation</a>.</p>
  </div>
   <div id="cards" class="one-half column" style="margin-top: 5%">
   <img class="card-image" src="img/sample.png">
    <h4>Basic Page</h4>
    <p>This index.html page is a placeholder with the CSS, font and favicon. It's just waiting for you to add some content! If you need some help hit up the <a href="http://www.getskeleton.com">Skeleton documentation</a>.</p>
  </div>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do it in plain css unless you work with columns instead of rows (and that breaks content importance).

What you want is [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/) or another javascript alternative.

Also, your html has errors, you cannot use the same id more than once. Change it to class='cards' and if you want to use masonry you have to put every card inside the same div, so in this case, inside the same row.

Then you can call it

```
$('.row').masonry({
  itemSelector: '.cards',
  columnWidth: 200 //this is an example.
});
```

Since masonry is responsive, you can forget about skeleton for this part.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help! So can I use Masonry with Skeleton?

Comment: Yeah, but you won't take advantage of rows and column class since it will override it. Just make a div, and put all the cards in there. Then call masonry using that div class or id instead of '.row' on the example I gave you